# У меня есть выполняемый скрипт, как мне считать информацию с терминала VS Code, о том, что конкретный скрипт запустился, а именно вывести его название

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, test-automation

Мне нужно получить эту строчку и вывести ее в консоль[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать ?
Пишу в VSCode на JS, используя WebDriverIO. В package.json у меня есть скрипты, задача - получить значение из терминала, которое будет являться имени исполняемого скрипта, как показано на картинке и записать в какую-то переменную (после запуска данного скрипта). По факту это всегда вторая строчка в терминале, после запуска скрипта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И всё же, в чём ваш вопрос? Имя теста вы знаете - это ваш `createNewBook.js`. То, что идёт перед именем вашего скрипта, не меняется от запуска к запуску. Поэтому вам достаточно скопировать выделенную вами строчку и всего лишь подставить вместо `createNewBook.js` имя тестового скрипта. В чём подвох?

Comment: Простите за неясность, у меня запускается множество скриптов друг за другом, мне нужно получать не их имя, а само значение, добавлю еще один скриншот (все что идет после "test:chrome:ui":) И нужно как-то вытащить именно эту команду в виде строки

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю. Все команды у вас записаны в `package.json`. Зачем вам отслеживать запуск скриптов и куда-то их записывать? Откройте `package.json`, извлеките поле `scripts`, в нём все команды перечислены.

Comment: Мне нужно это для того, чтобы потом извлечь из этой самой строки название тест сьюта и использовать в describe блоках, чтобы видеть какой именно тест не прошел и с каким именно env значением, в каком сьюте. Потому что тест у меня один, а вот данные для входа на сайт использует разные, вот по этому и есть нужда как-то их отличать именно после запуска

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно, при чем тут `bash`. Дело же явно в Windows происходит.

Средствами PowerShell можно сделать вот так:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='cross-env'" | select -Property CommandLine
```

Comment: а можно как-то в переменную это записать? Чтобы потом выводить с помощью console.log() ?

Comment: @Vladeezy ваша вера в мои телепатические способности подкупает. Вы правда думаете, что я вот прям сразу постиг вашу постановку задачи - в какой окружении вы выполняете код, на каком языке, с какими доступными API? Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и подробно опишите, чем вы занимаетесь и что хотите получить.

Comment: обновил описание